# STM32F4 What will happen if both Preempt Priority and SubPriority of IRQa and IRQb are same?

Tags: arm, stm32, interrupt, interrupt-handling, stm32f4discovery

Lets say
        (***IRQa*** ,***0***,***0***) in line 1
        (***IRQb***, ***0***, **0**)  in line 2

## Which interrupt is serviced first ?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @old_timer -  Sarthak Sharma is a new contributor...       It is not very simple to try this out and get a conclusive result out of it (without misinterpretation). Therefore, it is justified to ask this question (or to look it up in the documentation).

Comment: the next question would have been what did you find when you read the documentation, but someone asked that already...new contributor or not still need to do your own research and have a real question based on that.  new contributor doesnt mean new to software development.

Comment: @old_timer - I agree. Trying this out is high-level, looking it up in documentation is entry-level.

Answer (score 2):

From ARM Developer,2.3.6. Interrupt priority grouping (https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0553/a/the-cortex-m4-processor/exception-model/interrupt-priority-grouping):

> Only the group priority determines preemption of interrupt exceptions.
>   When the processor is executing an interrupt exception handler,
>   another interrupt with the same group priority as the interrupt being
>   handled does not preempt the handler,
>
> If multiple pending interrupts have the same group priority, the
>   subpriority field determines the order in which they are processed.
>   **If multiple pending interrupts have the same group priority and subpriority, the interrupt with the lowest IRQ number is processed
>   first.**

Comment: Add also that they will not preempt each other.